# How to split a string in MVC and build a ul

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, html-lists

I need to split a comma separated string and build a `<ul>`.

I cannot seem to find the sweet spot.

**Here is my code:**

```
  <ul>
            @{
                string[] ps = Model.ProductsServices.Split(',');

                for (byte i = 0; i < ps.Length; i++)
                {
                    <li>ps[i]</li>
                }
            }
        </ul>
```

**Here is the result of the above code.**

[image: How to build list items ul in MVC]

Comment: Inside the body of your for loop, how are the `<ul>` tags distinguished from the variable you are accessing? Maybe try `string.format?` to seperate static text (in your case the tags) from the data being inserted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting an `@` in from of `ps[i]`.

```
<ul>
    @{
        string[] ps = Model.ProductsServices.Split(',');

        for (byte i = 0; i < ps.Length; i++)
        {
            <li>@ps[i]</li>
        }
    }
</ul>
```

---

Also there is little reason to use a plain `for` loop, a `foreach` is more readable and just as performant.

```
var ps = Model.ProductsServices.Split(',');
foreach (string service in ps)
{
    <li>@service</li>
}
```

Comment: +1. `byte` should pretty much never be used in regular code... `int` (or `var` which would implicitly define variable as `int` in this case) is much easier to read. It also have good chance to work correctly for something like 300 items unlike `byte`.

Comment: In this case there is not 300 items. I always keep up with the data sizes and use byte, short, int, and long where needed. A lot of people will default at int. In the above example it really would not have mattered if I used long because there is not much processing on this page; however, I'm  so use to writing code that it is very serious to allocate the correct sizes of my data to where is just comes natural now. The for i loop provides the best performance.

Comment: In a lot of cases though, using byte will require unnecessary casts and actually be detrimental to performance.